# Facebook message when publish to wall from app

Tags: facebook

I'm looking the documentation about publishing the message to wall from Facebook app
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/, but 'message' option in "Direct URL Example" don't working for me. Why its happen?

I try to go with this url http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?%20%20app_id=123050457758183&%20%20link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&%20%20picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&%20%20name=Facebook%20Dialogs&%20%20caption=Reference%20Documentation&%20%20description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&%20%20message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&%20%20redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
and don't see "Facebook Dialogs are so easy!" message in textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook stopping support message option.

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in the URL where you shouldn't. All those %20 characters are spaces that shouldn't be there. The decoded URL you are trying to load looks something like this:

?  apps_id=...&  link=...&  picture=...

You have to get rid of the spaces before the parameter names.

Comment: Ok, but this short example http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response&message=test also doesn't work.

Comment: Facebook stopping support message option